# How this adapter inside the bearing is called? How to find/make a replacement?

Tags: bearings

This is an ABEC7 bearing with a 12 mm hole and a 19 mm external diameter:

[image]

It has a tightly mounted adapter (the black part), which in turn has a 6mm hole and two external diameters: 12 mm (partially hidden in the bearing, partially visible) and 15.5 mm (fully visible). The adapter is required for a common 5 mm axle of two bearings. The wider parts are on the outside. The narrower parts are fixed into a common wheel.

Unfortunately, the adapter is made of aluminium and I would want one which is made of steel. Thus the questions:

1. What is the proper technical name of the adapter?
2. Can it be bought "off the shelf"?
3. If not, can it be easily ordered from a typical metal workshop?

EDIT: I was asked for a precise drawing and so I attach it. As seen, I need two versions, both with an increased internal diameter. I could adapt, however, an off-the-shelf part into any of these versions with a drill, apart from the 16/18 mm outer diameter, which is better but not necessary.

[image]

Comment: Is it just an adapter to allow a larger diameter bearing to be used with a smaller diameter shaft, for whatever reason? I've designed such. If it got pressed into the bearing, it might be hard to get out if the inner race is totally covered by the 15.5mm diameter on the side it was pressed in on // If it is in fact such an adapter, it's important to figure out why the larger bearing was needed, and if there are special features of the bearing (e.g. for axial load).

Comment: Yes it is an adapter for two bearings having a long common shaft. The shaft is thinner probably to reduce weight.

Comment: Great. Then try to figure out if the bearing was an angular-contact type, i.e. designed for axial load in addition to radial

Comment: @PeteW I guess yes. The problem is, I want to apply a substantial moment load, probably much larger than intended by the producer of the bearing.

Comment: if axial load is large, you need that type of brg. // if significant moment (is other end of shaft not supported?), do the calculation, consider adding another bearing, etc

Comment: Radial bearings can typically handle axial loads equivalent to 50% of their rated radial capacity. You may not need a new bearing.

Comment: @PeteW Yes, I decided to not support the other end. That's why I want to increase the axle's diameter from 5 mm to 8 mm and use a class 10.9 steel.

Comment: This is getting complicated, more than just a bearing and sleeve part ID. Maybe submit another question on that aspect of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the name, I don't think that there is an official technical name, but then again I'm not a native speaker (nor can I speculate on the function of this shaft which in some cases might lend it  a name).

However, if you go to any workshop with a lathe you should be able to order one of those. The main thing that you need to determine (apart from diameters, lengths and hole sizes) is the interference fit (since its tightly mounted).

You can always take the old part and ask them to replicate it (since I surmise that you might not be adequately technically inclined to calculate and provide the necessary tolerances for the interference fit).

Comment: This is sound advice. I would prefer to be given a part and told "make this in steel" than given a questionable drawing without tolerances

Comment: If it is an adapter type part, the 6mm center hole may also figure into the alignment stack-up.... (e.g. if the mating part has a 5.9x mm "nose")

Comment: from the image angle there are a lot of things that cannot be determined.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I attach a precise drawing. The tolerance is mostly important for the part in contact with the bearing. There is about half a millimeter of clearance between the axle and the adapter.

Comment: @NMech I precised the question.

Comment: @scriptfoo - good, but the tolerances are critical here......

Comment: @PeteW I can be wrong here, but I guess that +- 0.05 mm for the cylindrical surface which touches the bearing, otherwise +- 0.2 mm and the widest flat side should be at 90 deg +- 0.5 deg to the cylindrical surface mentioned, to minimize the moment load. But might be, you know better, given the application details in the question.

Comment: need the full bearing detail from mfg or the standard class.  sorry I can't give you a number

Comment: @PeteW The bearing is ABEC7 6901 2RS 43.

Comment: good. put that in the body of your post